# Set log xticks in matplotlib for a linear plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider

```
xdata=np.random.normal(5e5,2e5,int(1e4))
plt.hist(np.log10(xdata), bins=100)
plt.show()
plt.semilogy(xdata)
plt.show()
```

is there any way to display xticks of the first plot (plt.hist) as in the second plot's yticks? For good reasons I want to histogram the `np.log10(xdata)` of `xdata` but I'd like to set minor ticks to display as usual in a log scale (even considering that the exponent is linear...)

In other words, I want the x_axis of this plot:

[image]

to be like the y_axis

[image]

of the 2nd plot, without changing the spacing between major ticks (e.g., adding log marks between 5.5 and 6.0, without altering these values)

Comment: This makes no sense:  (e.g., adding log marks between 5.5 and 6.0, without altering these values)

Comment: "way to display xticks of the first plot (plt.hist) as in the second plot's yticks?" was misleading, you want to search for "histogram logarithmic x-axis" (as well as see the [Proper histogram plot answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73690180/11815313)) and then update the question. (I'll then delete my other answer - just keep it for now as is shows the misunderstanding the same way as in @Lucas M. Uriarte answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just kept for now for clarification purpose. Will be deleted when the question is revised.

---

**Disclaimer:**

- As [Lucas M. Uriarte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14543462/lucas-m-uriarte) already mentioned that isn't an expected way of changing axis ticks.
- **x axis ticks and labels don't represent the plotted data**
- You should at least always provide that information along with such a plot.

**The plot**

From seeing the result I kinda understand where that special plot idea is coming from - still there should be a preferred way (e.g. conversion of the data in advance) to do such a plot instead of 'faking' the axis.

[image]

**Explanation** how that special axis transfer plot is done:

- original x-axis is hidden
- a [twiny](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.twiny.html) axis is added

  - note that its y-axis is hidden by default, so that doesn't need handling
- twiny x-axis is set to log and the 2nd plot y-axis limits are transferred

  - subplots used to directly transfer the 2nd plot y-axis limits

    - use variables if you need to stick with your two plots
- twiny x-axis is moved from top (twiny default position) to bottom (where the original x-axis was)

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(42)  # just to have repeatable results for the answer
xdata=np.random.normal(5e5,2e5,int(1e4))

plt.figure()
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(7,10), facecolor=(1, 1, 1))

# 1st plot
axs[0].hist(np.log10(xdata), bins=100)  # plot the data on the normal x axis
axs[0].axes.xaxis.set_visible(False)  # hide the normal x axis

# 2nd plot
axs[1].semilogy(xdata)


# 1st plot - twin axis
axs0_y_twin = axs[0].twiny()  # set a twiny axis, note twiny y axis is hidden by default
axs0_y_twin.set(xscale="log")  
# transfer the limits from the 2nd plot y axis to the twin axis
axs0_y_twin.set_xlim(axs[1].get_ylim()[0], 
                     axs[1].get_ylim()[1]) 

# move the twin x axis from top to bottom
axs0_y_twin.tick_params(axis="x", which="both", bottom=True, top=False, 
                        labelbottom=True, labeltop=False)

# Disclaimer
disclaimer_text = "Disclaimer: x axis ticks and labels don't represent the plotted data"
axs[0].text(0.5,-0.09, disclaimer_text, size=12, ha="center", color="red", 
            transform=axs[0].transAxes)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

***Proper histogram plot with logarithmic x-axis***:

[image]

**Explanation:**

1. Cut off negative values

   - The randomly generated example data likely contains still some negative values

     - activate the commented code lines at the beginning to see the effect
   - [logarithmic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) isn't defined for values <= 0

     - while the 2nd plot just deals with y-axis log scaling (negative values are just out of range), the 1st plot doesn't work with negative values in the BINs range
   - probably real world working data won't be <= 0, otherwise keep that in mind
2. BINs should be aligned to log scale as well

   - otherwise the 'BINs widths' distribution looks off

     - switch `#` on the `plt.hist(` statements in the 1st plot section to see the effect)
3. `xdata` (not `np.log10(xdata)`) to be plotted in the histogram

   - that 'workaround' with plotting `np.log10(xdata)` probably was the root cause for the misunderstanding in the comments

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(42)  # just to have repeatable results for the answer

xdata=np.random.normal(5e5,2e5,int(1e4))
# MIN_xdata, MAX_xdata = np.min(xdata), np.max(xdata) 
# print(f"{MIN_xdata}, {MAX_xdata}")  # note the negative values

# cut off potential negative values (log function isn't defined for <= 0 )
xdata = np.ma.masked_less_equal(xdata, 0)
MIN_xdata, MAX_xdata = np.min(xdata), np.max(xdata)
# print(f"{MIN_xdata}, {MAX_xdata}")

# align the bins to fit a log scale
bins = 100
bins_log_aligned = np.logspace(np.log10(MIN_xdata), np.log10(MAX_xdata), bins)

# 1st plot
plt.hist(xdata, bins = bins_log_aligned)  # note: xdata (not np.log10(xdata) )
# plt.hist(xdata, bins = 100)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()

# 2nd plot
plt.semilogy(xdata)
plt.show()
```